# How to re-encode documents back to original text?

Tags: character-encoding

I made a big mistake and changed my code editor in the middle of work. I was using sublime2 and dreamweaver and it was perfect untill i switched to aptana. I opened all the documents, continued to work and saved them, naturally . The thing is aptana saved these documents with ISO encoding. Recently i learned that aptana have some issues about encoding stuff. Anyway ...

Code is still working, i can still keep working on it. However at the end i have to read hundreds of lines and change the faulty characters back to original state.

Is there a tool for reading files and change the decoded characters to their original state? (Except the find & replace all :) )

Comment: Please post a sample, both of text and of its actual byte representation.

Comment: @KArol S. in the current doc "ö"s are "Ã¶" , "ş"s are "¼d" , "ü"s are "Ã¼" . in Notepad++ none of the encoding option corrected these.

Comment: While it would be handy if you had also posted bytes, from these snippets alone I see it's broken beyond automated repair. So, it's find&replace time.